# Expressive adequacy

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

After reading a few others posts on this site, I am still struggling in showing how sets are incomplete.

(a) Show that {$↔,\bot, ∧$} is functionally complete, but that no proper subset is.

(b) is solved! :)

<strike>(b) Assume that $c$ is a 2-place connective. Show that if either $f_c(\top, \top) = \top$ or $f_c(\bot, \bot) = \bot$, then {$c$} is not complete.</strike>

For (b), I understand that for {$\uparrow$} and {$\downarrow$}, the only functionally complete 2-place connectives, that $f_{\uparrow}(\top, \top) = \bot$ and $f_{\uparrow}(\bot, \bot) = \top$. The same results apply for $f_{\downarrow}$. I just can't see how to then apply this to prove $f_c(\top, \top) = \top$ means {$c$} is incomplete.

Comment: If you *know already* that $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$ are the only functionally complete $2$-place connectives, you're done: knowing $f_c(\top,\top)=\top$ immediately tells you that $c\not=\uparrow$ and $c\not=\downarrow$, so $c$ must not be functionally complete (and similarly if you know $f_c(\perp,\perp)=\perp$).

Answer (score 1):

As Noah points out in the comments, you know that $c$ cannot be either the  $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$, and since those are the only two connectives that are by themselves complete, you know $c$ is not complete.

However, I doubt that this proof is 'acceptable', or at least probably not what was expected of you. Probably you had to give a more direct proof why such a $c$ is not complete. Well, think about it. Suppose you have any number of connectives $c$, applied to any number of instances of $\top$, e.g. $(\top c \top) c (\top c (\top c \top))$ ... if you evaluate this, you'll of course get $\top$ for any expression; you';ll never get $\bot$.

Now, to make that idea into a rigorous proof, use induction: prove by (strong) induction on the number of operators $c$ in any statement $\phi$ that is composed of $c$'s and $\top$, that $\phi$  will always evaluate to $\top$. I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: Okay, thank you! For (a), what does it mean that $\bot$, but not $\top$, is in {$↔,\bot, ∧$}? Does this mean that I cannot assign $\top$ to any sentences? If so, how can I say that {$↔,\bot, ∧$} is complete?

Comment: @vundabar No. It means that $\bot$ is used as a symbol with which you can create expressions. Its value is always False though. So, with that, the expression $P \leftrightarrow \bot$ is equivalent to the expression $\neg P$, meaning that you can express $\neg$ using $\leftrightarrow$ and $\bot$. And, if you already have shown that $\{ \neg, \land \}$ is complete, you therefore have that $\{ \leftrightarrow, \bot, \land \}$ is complete

Comment: got it! Now, in trying to show that {$∧, ⊥$} (as a subset of {$↔, ⊥, ∧$}) is $not$ expressively adequate, I know from research that neither connective is monotone: changing the truth value of any of the operator's 'inputs' can never change the value of an argument from a T to an F. But while I know $that$ ∧ doesn't have this property, I'm not sure exactly $why$ this means the subset is not adequate. Any ideas?

Comment: @vundabar But when you have $P$ being true, then $P \land \bot$ is false ...  So, instead of changing a T into a F, look into how you would change a F into a T.

Answer (score 1):

For (a), to prove that a set of connectives is functionally complete, an "induction on formulas" should be done by demonstrating that the other known connectives in the logic can be derived using our given set. In our case, the other connectives to be derived are $\{\vee,\top,\rightarrow,\neg\}$ or just $\{\vee, \top, \neg\}$ because $\rightarrow$ can be derived already using $\vee$ and $\neg$ $(p\rightarrow q=\neg p\vee q)$.

The formula $\neg p$ can be derived using $p\leftrightarrow\bot$ because when $p$ is $\top$, "$p\leftrightarrow\bot$" gives $\top\leftrightarrow\bot=\bot$ and when $p$ is $\bot$, "$p\leftrightarrow\bot$" gives $\bot\leftrightarrow\bot=\top$.

It's now obvious that $\top$ can be derived using $\bot\rightarrow\bot$.

Finally, $p\vee q$ can also be derived from $\{\leftrightarrow,\bot,\wedge\}$. Hint: De Morgan's Theorem.

Comment: Thank you! Got the last one! $p ∨ q \Leftrightarrow ((p\leftrightarrow\bot) ∧ (q\leftrightarrow\bot))\leftrightarrow\bot$